# SQL Server 2012 Full Text Search on RTF

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, rtf

I have my Database running on a SQL Server 2012. One Column of my Table contains RTF Text. The Datatype of the Column is nvarchar(MAX).

I want setup a full text search for this column which analyses the rtf and searches only in the real text, so that I don't get rtf Tags as result.

As I understand, parsing rtf should already be part of the SQL Server. But I don't get it working :-(

I did following:

- Create a full text catalog
- Select the column containing rtf and add a full_text Index

But I still get wrong results

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE
CONTAINS(myRtfColumn,'rtf')
```

--> still get all columns, as 'rtf' is a keyword

Any Ideas what I doing wrong? Do I have to activate rtf-Search for my SQL Server or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

A full text search works only on text columns. You are inserting into your database binary stuff -> rtf. When you have chosen nvarchar you told the sql server you want to store text, but you are storing binary stuff. For binary stuff use varbinary(max) instead.

The problem will still remain, because the index routines don't know how to interpret richtext - what are control chars what is content.

let us talk about the interpreter/filter

documentation says:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms142531(v=SQL.105).aspx

> varbinary(max) or varbinary data
>   A single varbinary(max) or varbinary column can store many types of documents. SQL Server 2008 supports any document type for which a filter is installed and available in the operative system. The document type of each document is identified by the file extension of the document. For example, for a .doc file extension, full-text search uses the filter that supports Microsoft Word documents. For a list of available document types, query the sys.fulltext_document_types catalog view.
>
> Note that the Full-Text Engine can leverage existing filters that are installed in the operating system. Before you can use operating-system filters, word breakers, and stemmers, you must load them in the server instance, as follows:

Finally todo:

check if ".rtf" is as filter available.

```
EXEC sp_help_fulltext_system_components 'filter';
```

then add a calculated column to you table "typ" which always returns ".rtf"

```
alter table yourname add [Typ]  AS (CONVERT([nvarchar](8),'.rtf',0));
```

This can used now for the index as type specification.

Comment: Could you or someone else elaborate on how to parse out the rtf tags using this method? I don't quite understand. In my scenario, I simple need to SELECT from a table which has an nvarchar(max) field with some text in it surrounded by rtf tags. How do I use the filter in this case?

Comment: The parse is buildin in windows. this is all based on the ifilter interface. So if you need to fulltext pdf, go to adobe and download/install the ifilter for pdf. The fulltext engine need to know what is stored. this is the reason of the calculated column. You use that, in the fulltext index, to tell the engine which ifilter should used for you column.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it seems like all this will do is help me search through the text, meaning write a query that will filter on the text alone and ignore the rtf tags. I'm not interested in filtering out certain rows based on what is in the column, I want to simply `SELECT * FROM Table` and make it so that the column that has the rtf tags in it simply does not show the rtf tags in the query results. Or, if possible, show the original rtf-laden column *and* a different column in the result set that is the same as the original column but with the rtf tags removed.

Comment: Sorry if I'm bugging you about this 5 years after the original post. It's just that this problem has been driving me crazy for a few weeks now and the user still wants to see the column on the report *without* the rtf tags (I provided her the column on the report with the rtf tags included and she said it was too messy to read).

Comment: The question was about search within rtf. I think you have a different question. I suggest to create a new question "How to return a blob column having rtf stored as 
 plain text using sql.". I think the is no ready to use solution. I would try to write an own function using c# to call the rtf ifilter to get the plain text, like the search engine does.